# Get and set vue properties and access typescript based component methods globally (Need for automation/puppeteer)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, puppeteer

I am using one vue component with typescript, say annotator.

```
<annotator documentId="docId"></annotator>
```

my Typescript component class looks like below

```
    export default class AnnotatorComponent extends Vue {
    
        @Prop()
        public documentId?: number;
    
    
        applyAnnotation(annotations){
    
        }
    }
```

I am loading this component through puppeteer as below.

```
await page.goto('https://localhost:44375/annotator', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
```

Now component is loading as per my route definition.

But how to provide document id (can't use url. its too long as other parameters are also there. document id is just for example)

In addition, how can I call `applyAnnotation` method from puppeteer?

Comment: It's unclear how documentId and applyAnnotation are related. But you can't call applyAnnotation and can't tamper props from outside the app. If it's your app and you need it to be automated, consider providing a way to provide external data to it, e.g. through global vars. If you need applyAnnotation to be available outside the app, expose the method to `window`. Globals can be accessed with Puppeteer.

Comment: No. they are not related. I had same thought using `window`. I was wondering if there was official way to do so. :)

Comment: No, there's no other good way. It may be possible to dig deeply into the app with framework-specific debugging protocols but it's considered a hack and requires the app to be in dev mode. Isn't an option if it's your own app. Interacting through globals is a common way in such scenarios, not just Vue.